# Call Java code from C#

Tags: c#, java, class, parameters

I'm stuck on one thing i can't get solved. I have part of code, which is executed from command line like a charm. Works without any problem.

So, i will to try to call this command (same) out from C#.

That's the code i'm run from commandline.

> java -Xincgc -Xmx1024m -cp
>   "%APPDATA%.minecraft\bin\minecraft.jar;%APPDATA%.minecraft\bin\lwjgl.jar;%APPDATA%.minecraft\bin\lwjgl_util.jar;%APPDATA%.minecraft\bin\jinput.jar"
>   -Djava.library.path="%APPDATA%.minecraft\bin\natives" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft "NAME"

The part i'm trying to get it in C# looks like:

```
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "java";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-Xincgc -Xmx1024m -cp \"%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\bin\\minecraft.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\bin\\lwjgl.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\bin\\lwjgl_util.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\bin\\jinput.jar\" -Djava.library.path=\"%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\bin\\natives\" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft \"NAME\"";
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
proc.Start();
```

But, nothing happens at all. Is there something i'm doing wrong? 
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expand the environment variables in the `Arguments` using [`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx).

```
string args = "-Xincgc -Xmx1024m -cp \"%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\bin\\minecraft.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\bin\\lwjgl.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\bin\\lwjgl_util.jar;%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\bin\\jinput.jar\" -Djava.library.path=\"%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\bin\\natives\" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft \"NAME\"";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(args);
```

BTW - you can use a [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) to make that argument string more readable.

```
@"-Xincgc -Xmx1024m -cp ""%APPDATA%\.minecraft\bin\minecraft.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\bin\lwjgl.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\bin\lwjgl_util.jar;%APPDATA%\.minecraft\bin\jinput.jar"" -Djava.library.path=""%APPDATA%\.minecraft\bin\natives"" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft ""NAME""";
```